# Couldn't find executable named tf_brodcaster below

Tags: ros, catkin, broadcaster, robot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am new to ROS

My question is similar to a [previous question asked](http://answers.ros.org/question/211427/stackpackage-robot_setup_tf-not-found/).

I am following the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF

And I am stuck with the robot_setup_tf part. Whereby I run the command

```
rosrun robot_setup_tf tf_broadcaster
```

Initially I get

```
package robot_setup_tf not found
```

I have tried the sourcing the `setup.bash` file in my `catkin_ws/devel`, (From the 1st link)

```
source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

It solves the previous error, however, now I get a new error

```
Couldn't find executable named tf_brodcaster below /home/user1/catkin_ws/src/robot_setup_tf
```

I am running on ROS indigo. Would appreciate assistance!

Thanks alot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216391/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-tf_brodcaster-below/) by [Greyshades](https://answers.ros.org/users/23661/greyshades/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> "Couldn't find executable named tf_brodcaster below [..]"
> ```

Is this an actual copy/paste? Because there is a typo there: it's `tf_broadcaster`, not `tf_brodcaster` (note the missing `a`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Greyshades](https://answers.ros.org/users/23661/greyshades/) on 2015-08-24**:
Apologies for the typo. Yes it worked after I fixed the typo! Thanks for spotting it!
Thanks again for your help!